# Bundle Identifier with Enterprise account

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

We have an app ready for App Store submission. The only problem is that we were working on it with an enterprise account and we realized only now that it is not ok for submitting to the AppStore. Now my question is: If we created a new account that is abel to submit the app and added that to the team of the enterprise account, will we be able to use the same boundle identifier? We need the same becouse we use a framework that is identifiing the app by bundle identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've contacted Apple with this problem but they couldn't help us with this so the answer is basically **NO**.If you have an Enterprise account and you want to publish an app, you will need a new bundle ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to go through the process to transfer the app to the new account.

Once an App ID is created, it normally belongs to the organization that created and cannot be reused by another team.

Here is the process for transferring the app:

> Can I transfer an app to another developer's iTunes Connect account?
>   Yes, you can transfer your app to another developer on iTunes Connect
>   whenever your app is in a transferable state.
>
> Transferring the ownership of an app does not affect the app’s
>   availability on the App Store. All ratings and reviews will be
>   transferred and your customers will continue to have access to all
>   available app updates.
>
> What are the requirements for transferring an app? To transfer an app,
>   make sure that:
>
> The transferor and the recipient have active developer accounts and
>   have accepted the most current version of all master agreements that
>   are currently in effect The app has at least one approved version The
>   app is in the Ready for Sale, Rejected, Developer Rejected, or
>   Developer Removed from Sale state Any associated in-app purchases are
>   in the Ready to Submit, Ready for Sale, Rejected, Developer Removed
>   from Sale, or Approved state You know the Apple ID of the recipient’s
>   Team Agent and their Team ID What information do I need from the
>   recipient to transfer an app? To transfer an app, you must know the
>   Apple ID of the recipient’s Team Agent and their Team ID.

And a few more things from Apple's FAQ:

> Which iTunes Connect user role can transfer an app? The iTunes Connect
>   user with the Legal role, also referred to as the Team Agent, can
>   initiate and accept an app transfer.
>
> How long will the transfer process take? The transfer process for apps
>   that are not Game Center enabled can take up to three hours from when
>   the recipient accepts the transfer. If the app is Game Center enabled,
>   or the app has any export compliance issues, the entire transfer
>   process can take up to two business days.

Comment: The problem is that The app is not published yet and the account that holds the bundle ID (the enterprise account) has no access to the iTunes Connect

Comment: Ah, you are likely going to need to make a support call to Apple to resolve this.